# Running an Azure role in multiple regions?

Tags: azure

I currently have a production deployment in West Europe and would like to create another instance that is running in the US.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible at instance level. But you can have geographically distributed applications at hosted service level, using the [Traffic Manager](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/). This means you'll need a hosted service for your West Europe deployment and one for your US deployment.

This blog post explains how to make it work: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CloudPowerHowToScaleAzureWebsitesGloballyWithTrafficManager.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that article was out of date as it seems a bit clumsy to have to deploy the same application for each region every time you want to update it. Having to change the application settings for each region is also another pain point!

Comment: That's true, but if you think about it, that's a small price to pay to  have a geographically distributed application

Comment: I've got it all running now :)
Oh, the app settings were only needed for the sample so it's less hassle than I thought. I know I'm being picky but they spoiled us with 1 click deployment.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a new hosted service in the US datacenter/region that you want to deploy to.  Then deploy your service to that new hosted service.  You can use [Windows Azure Traffic Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/hh745750.aspx) to direct users to the deployment closest to them (one of the three policies that can be established - performance, round robin, and/or failover)